# Custom drawfunc in KineticJS

Tags: kineticjs

I have gone through  few articles for detecting hit only on the perimeter of circle or rectangle. Some workarounds for implementing it is done by doing maths on click event of the shape or creating groups. That's fine. **But is there any way we can implement this by  creating a custom draw function that just draws the perimeter of a rectangle, circle (stroke only).**

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is really simple if you set your hit function.  Here's a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/L3EST/

The key is to use the strokeShape() method in your custom hit function instead of fillStrokeShape(), which is what the default hit function uses.

```
  var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 10,
    drawHitFunc: function(context) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.rect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
      context.closePath();
      context.strokeShape(this);
    }
  });
```

After attaching events as is done in the jsfiddle, when you mouseover or mouseout of the perimeter of the shape, the events are fired.

Comment: +1 Nice...I didn't know this was possible (my bad about giving wrong advice in my answer--deleted that answer).

Comment: no problemo!  The entirety of KineticJS is not yet fully documented.  There's tons of gems in there that a lot of people don't know about.. yet :P

Comment: If i set the strokeWidth to 1px, it is difficult to detect the hit, Is it possible to increase the hitarea with certain pixel around the perimeter, without using fillStrokeShape() and not increasing the strokeWidth? :P

Comment: yep.  instead of using strokeShape(), just stroke the shape yourself via context.setAttr('lineWidth', 20); context.stroke();

Comment: updated the drawHitFunc, plz refer http://jsfiddle.net/gokuldahal/4yggT/ but events didn't fire.

Comment: you need to also set the strokeStyle.  Here's the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/R8hp7/ and here's the context stroke method as a reference https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/blob/master/src/Context.js#L583